# Python 2.7 getfullargspec equivalent

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can some one please point me to the right direction? I am trying to identify the equivalent of getfullargspec available in python 3 inspect module but without success for now.

Comment: Since you don't have keyword only arguments in Python 2.7, won't inspect.getargspec be what you want?

Comment: I was thinking at it as well. If you post it as an answer I'll vote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [getargspec](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec). It is closest to `getfullargspec`